# How can I use this code to strip html tags form a form field?

Tags: html, tags, strip, formfield

I am using some basic script to strip HTML tags. Here is the code for that I am using. How can I get it to do it to a text field named `['msge']` when it's posted?

```
function transform_HTML($string, $len = null) {     
    $string == ($_POST['msge']);
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = utf8_decode($string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
    $string = str_replace("#", "&#35;", $string);
    $string = str_replace("%", "&#37;", $string);
    $len = intval($len);
    if ($len > 0) {$string = substr($string, 0,$len);}
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: `$string == ($_POST['msge']);` makes no sense.

Comment: Ohh, whoops. That wasnt supposed to be there, lol.